# Redirect 301 en .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hola tengo un wordpress con varios articulos que quiero Redireccionar:

Los articulos que dan error 404 cuelgan de la categoria /actualidad-noticias/ con una estructura similar a /actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm y quiero que se redireccionen a http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/

Pero por alguna razón no se hace correctamente. decir que lo hago desde el fichero .htaccess que ya contiene otras redirecciones similares y funcionan correctamente

La línea de código es la siguiente:

`Redirect 301 /actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/`

¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona justo esta redirección?

Otra que tampo funciona:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm$ http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Ponlo de esta manera: `Redirect 301 /actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm /ciudadania-digital`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano nada ni con "/" final tampoco. de:  http://www.ejemplo.net/actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm a http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/ no entiendo como no funciona, por más que pruebo con otras expresiones regulares... Gracias.

Comment: Yo tengo un sitio WP y las redirecciones me funcionan así sin problemas. ¿Seguro que lo estás poniendo en el `.htaccess` adecuado? Debe ser el del directorio raíz de tu sitio, donde están los archivos y directorios como `wp-config.php` y demás.

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, estoy con el .htaccess redireccionando otras categorías y noticias y sin problema, todo correcto. Es la categoría /actualidad-noticias/ y las noticias que cuelgan de ella las que no redirecioan correctamente con el Redirect 301. Gracias de nuevo por el interés.

Comment: Pero cuando entras a `actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm`  ¿qué ocurre en realidad y qué comportamiento esperas? Lo que yo entiendo es que quieres redireccionarlo a `www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital`  ¿estamos hablando de una redirección en el mismo dominio, cierto (o sea todo está en `ejemplo.net`)?  ¿La dirección `www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/` es realmente funcional?

Comment: `http://www.ejemplo.net/actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm` es una página con una noticia dentro de una categoría que ya no funcina (se ha creado el mismo artículo en wordpress) esa página antigua genera un error 404 cuando se intenta acceder a través de otros enlaces (webs externas con el enlace). La idea es redireccionar esas noticias a los artículos creados en wordpress que están en `http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/` para que en vez de dar error 404 aparezcan los creados recientemente.

Comment: Yaaaa, pero `http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/` **¿funciona realmente?**  ¿Probaste esa URL?  Si funciona y lo pones como te dije al principio, ¿qué ocurre, sigue arrojando error 404?

Comment: Sí, http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/ funciona la url y contiene un artículo. Si hago la redirección: `Redirect 301 /actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm /ciudadania-digital ` el resultado que obtengo es el error 404 en http://www.ejemplo.net/actualidad-noticias/ciudadania-digital-mayo-2010.shtm no hace "ni amago" de ir a `http://www.ejemplo.net/ciudadania-digital/`

Comment: Y si haces pruebas con una redirección 302 (temporal) en una nueva sesión de incógnito? Solo para estar seguro de que tu navegador realmente está conectándose al servidor...

Comment: Hola @RockoDev gracias por el interés, tampoco funciona, el tema es que otras categorías similares las estoy haciendo sin problema… con el primer ejemplo del tema principal… Estoy probando otras formas sin suerte como:   `RewriteRule ^actualidad\-noticias/ciudadania\-digital\-mayo\-2010\.shtm$ /ciudadania-digital/? [L,R=301]`  Gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner aquí la URL que se pone en el navegador cuando te da el error 404. Da la impresión de que a su vez rediriges las categorías o algo así, interpretando esta parte  `actualidad-noticias` como una categoría a redirigir... otra cosa es que debes revisar tu `.htaccess`, no sea que haga más redirecciones que impliquen a esa URL o a una parte de ella.

Comment: Actualizo con la solución: en `/actualidad-noticias/` se creo un subdirectorio y contenia su propio `.htaccess` he pasado ahi las redirecciones y funcionan correctamente, ahora falta por ver como mostrar `/actualidad-noticias/` para que se vea la pagina que se mostraba antes con todos los articulos a modo de lista ya que al hacer las redirecciones solo muestra la pagina del servidor el index of/ de ese directorio